How to solve "Network unreachable" when using gpg --search?
When I run gpg --search I always get Network is unreachable
gpg --search-key xxx
gpg: enabled compatibility flags:
gpg: error searching keyserver: Network is unreachable
gpg: keyserver search failed: Network is unreachable

I'm 100% positive there is no network issue I can ping keys.openpgp.org.
How can I go about fixing this?
I have tried changing ~/.gnupg/dirnmgr.conf with the options standard-resolver and no-use-tor but the problem persist. What can be the source of the problem?

In order for the changes in ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf to take effect you need to restart the dirnmgr process with:
pkill dirmngr 

So in order to solve the Network is unreachable edit ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf and set the contents to:
keyserver hkps://keys.openpgp.org
no-use-tor
standard-resolver
disable-ipv6

Then perform pkill dirmngr and retry the gpg --search
gpg --search xxxx@yyy.com
gpg: data source: https://keys.openpgp.org:443
(1) XXXX XXXX XXXX <xxxx.xxxx@gmail.com>
     4096 bit RSA key F4EF621095F31DCA, created: 2023-02-23

